# Installing CPLEX for Python fails: "ERROR: No CPLEX python wrappers at..."

Tags: python, cplex

I tried to install CPLEX for Python. I managed to install CPLEX on my macbook without too much struggle, but now I came across some problem I can't get over alone. I tried to follow [these steps](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=cplex-setting-up-python-api), with python3 instead of python, but that seems to fail.

When I type in the command

`python3 /Applications/CPLEX_Studio2211/python/setup.py install`

I get the message

`ERROR: No CPLEX python wrappers at /Applications/CPLEX_Studio2211/cplex/python/3.11`

There's no folder 3.11 in that directory, so I guess I understand why that doesn't work, but I have no idea what to do with it. How could I work around this?

Answer (score 2):

CPLEX does not have support for Python 3.11 yet. A similar question from the IBM community forum:

**Posted Tue January 17, 2023 10:51 AM**

> We do not have python 3.11 CPLEX packages yet. We only support until
> 3.10 with the latest versions.
>
> Vincent Beraudier

https://community.ibm.com/community/user/ai-datascience/discussion/cplex-python-311

You need to downgrade your Python version.